# Redis ZCARD multiple keys (redis-rb)

Tags: ruby, redis

Is it possible to get count of multiple sorted sets in Redis?

I want something like:

```
redis.zcard(["YOLO", "YOLOSWAG"])
```

That should return count of YOLO and YOLOSWAG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands documentation doesn't say it takes multiple arguments, so it doesn't.

You can pipeline as many `ZCARD` requests as you want, though, something like (forgive my lousy ruby)

```
counts = redis.pipelined do
    ["YOLO", "YOLOSWAG"].each do |key|
       redis.zcard(key)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question, but if you're asking for a single count for both, you can actually do this faster than pipelining by using Lua. Idea is, you'll do all the additions server side, so instead of needing to transfer n numbers back over the network, you'll just transfer one. Not a big deal if you just have 2 keys for which you want cardinality, but figured I'd mention it anyway. It'd be something like (untested):

```
local total = 0
for i,k in ipairs(KEYS) do
    total = total + redis.call('ZCARD', k)
end
return total
```